# How to force Neo4j to use 2 indexes?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I mean, if I have two indexes:

```
CREATE INDEX ON :labelA(idA)
CREATE INDEX ON :labelB(idB)
```

And I do the following query:

```
MATCH (n:labelA {idA: valA})
MATCH (n:labelB {idB: valB})
CREATE (n)-[:Rel]->(B)
```

Does neo4j just use one of the indexes? If does, How do I force neo4j to use the 2 indexes?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently Neo will only use a maximum of one index to determine where to start walking the graph as part of query resolution. This is likely to change in the future. You can give Neo hints on which of the 2 or more indexes to use via USE INDEX but you can't get it to use more than one at this point.

Answer (score 1):

You could check if indexes are being used to find the nodes by prepending your query with `PROFILE`.

You could throw the query optimizer a hint something like this...

```
MATCH (a:labelA {idA: valA}), (b:labelB {idB: valB})
USING INDEX a:LabelA(idA)
USING INDEX b:LabelB(idB)
CREATE (a)-[:Rel]->(b)
```